# Pack two binaries(executables) into one file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-construction

I have two binary(executable) files A and B. At runtime, A may call B depending on given parameters. Is it possible to pack the two binaries into one file? So that, when needed, A do not have to look for B from other places. I have c source files for both. Each of them has a main() function, and I do not wish to modify the sources. It is also acceptable if there is a way to generate one executable at compile time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short no. You cannot have two main functions in one executable.

You could rename the two mains to `MethodA` and `MethodB` then decide which to call based on the arguments you send to main i.e. the `argv` in

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

Since you say you don't want to edit the source code, perhaps you are better off writing a script that calls the correct exe depending on the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an *archive* containing both the binaries and this can be extracted to same path on server. There-after either binaries can refer the other one from *current path*.

*CAUTION:*

*Demon*-izing them would spoil this approach.

Answer (score -1):

If you like to protect your second executable, You can use [Enigma Virtual Box](http://enigmaprotector.com/).